# Building a term-document matrix with given sets of text and tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-mining

I asked the same question in language R yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705895/how-to-build-a-term-document-matrix-from-a-set-of-texts-and-a-specific-set-of-te). But I now want to do this in Python as it seems faster and more memory-efficient.

I am using the [Python textmining library](http://www.christianpeccei.com/textmining/).

```
# create list of texts:
TextSet = ["java", "firefox java", "R php", "html php"]
TagSet = ["java", "php", "javascript"]

# CALCULATE TERM DOC MATRIX
tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()
for text in TextSet:
    tdm.add_doc(text)


# KEEP ONLY TERMS INSIDE TAGS LIST
# Code in R: tdm.onlytags <- tdm[rownames(tdm)%in%TagSet$tag,]
# Code in Python 2.7: ?????
```

How can I build a Term-Document-Matrix from a set of texts and a specific set of terms (tags) in Python?

Comment: why `textmining`? not the most documented or complet text mining solution. You can try [`gensim`](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html) for example, it is much better documented.

Comment: @alko I cannot find a simple Term-Document-Matrix example using gensim. Can you point me to one? I am open to any Python solution.

Comment: Do you want your matrix in a specific format ?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @alko, I strongly recommend gensim.

Just follow what's described in this page :
http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html#from-strings-to-vectors

I'll give the "hardest" part, building your own "texts

```
texts = [[word for word in doc.lower().split() if word in TagSet] for doc in TextSet]
```

from there you build the dictionary and convert to a matrix (should be a bunch of copy/paste from the gensim doc)

---

I wasn't able to test the textmining package, but if you still want to use it, you can get back a list of doc in the format you started with using :

newTextSet =  [" ".join(doc) for doc in texts]